# Paginated method to get all items

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, slim

I'm using slim php and i have this simple paginated end point to get all clients, i feel like i could do some things here better, so i would appreciate all suggestions, if possible please give me code example with suggested improvements. Thank you in advance.

```
$app->get('/api/clients', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    require_once 'dbConnect.php';
    require_once 'shared/securityService.php';
    $queryParams = $request->getQueryParams();

    $total = getTotalCount($mysqli, $queryParams["group"]);
    $pageSize = $queryParams["pageSize"];

    $totalPages = ceil($total / $pageSize);
    $offset = ($queryParams["page"] - 1)  * $pageSize;

    if(is_numeric($queryParams["group"])) {
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, firstName, lastName, birthDate, phoneNumber, address,
            contactPerson, contactPersonPhoneNumber FROM client WHERE groupId = ? ORDER BY
            id LIMIT $pageSize OFFSET $offset");

        $stmt->bind_param("i", $queryParams["group"]);
    } else {
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, firstName, lastName, birthDate, phoneNumber, address,
            contactPerson, contactPersonPhoneNumber FROM client 
            ORDER BY id LIMIT $pageSize OFFSET $offset");            
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $firstName, $lastName, $birthDate, $phoneNumber, 
        $address, $contactPerson, $contactPersonPhoneNumber);

    $data = null;

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $data['items'][] = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'firstName' => $firstName,
            'lastName' => $lastName,
            'birthDate' => $birthDate,
            'phoneNumber' => $phoneNumber,
            'address' => $address,
            'contactPerson' => $contactPerson,
            'contactPersonPhoneNumber' => $contactPersonPhoneNumber
        );
    }

    $data['totalItems'] = $total;

    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
    echo json_encode($data);
});

function getTotalCount($mysqli, $groupId) {
    if(is_numeric($groupId)) {
        $totalStmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM client WHERE groupId = ?");
        $totalStmt->bind_param("i", $groupId);
    } else {
        $totalStmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM client");
    }

    $totalStmt->execute();
    $totalStmt->bind_result($total);
    $totalStmt->fetch();
    $totalStmt->close();
    return $total;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**SQL Injection**

You are vulnerable to SQL injection via `pageSize`.

You need to use prepared statements for all values, not just some of them.

**Naming**

`total` and `getTotalCount` could be more descriptive. Currently, I don't really know what "total" means without looking at the code of the function. You also don't need "total" at all (it's assumed when talking about a count). `$clientCount = getClientCountForGroup($mysqli, $id)` would be easier to understand.

**Duplication**

Your two queries are basically duplicates apart from the WHERE clause. You may want to remove that duplication.

Comment: Thx for suggestions, what is best way to remove duplication ?

Answer (score 1):

**PDO**

Like I said before, moving to PDO will reduce the following code block

```
$stmt->bind_result($id, $firstName, $lastName, $birthDate, $phoneNumber, 
    $address, $contactPerson, $contactPersonPhoneNumber);

$data = null;

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $data['items'][] = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'firstName' => $firstName,
        'lastName' => $lastName,
        'birthDate' => $birthDate,
        'phoneNumber' => $phoneNumber,
        'address' => $address,
        'contactPerson' => $contactPerson,
        'contactPersonPhoneNumber' => $contactPersonPhoneNumber
    );
}
```

to

```
$data['items'] = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

**Programming**

It's always a good idea to create a function for the repetitive task. For running a query for example - an action that takes preparation, binding, execution, results retrieval. A function that takes a query and parameters as its arguments and returns the resulting data is always useful. A class would be better than a function though.

For example, it will make something like

```
function getClientCount($db, $groupId = 0) {
    if($groupId) {
        $stmt= $db->run("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM client WHERE groupId = ?",[$groupId]);
    } else {
        $stmt = $db->run("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM client");
    }
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
```